# Angular2 add styling when id of object > 100

Tags: typescript, angular

I have object markers with all different Id's, now I want to set extra styling when the `id > 100`

Here the code is:

```
<span *ngIf="result.object.reference > 100" class="tooltip-data">
   {{ result.resource.display_name }}
</span>
```

But how do I add extra styling like `style="left: 12px"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind to a style conditionally like

```
<span *ngIf="result.object.reference > 100" class="tooltip-data" 
    [style.left.px]="id > 100 ? 12 : 0">
```

or

```
<span *ngIf="result.object.reference > 100" class="tooltip-data" 
    [style.left]="id > 100 ? '12px' : '0px'">
```

If you don't want to set a style at all if `id <= 100` this might work

```
<span *ngIf="result.object.reference > 100" class="tooltip-data" 
    [ngStyle]="getStyle(id)">
```

```
noStyle = {};
gT100Style = {left: '12px'};
getStyle(id) {
  return id > 100 ? this.gT100Style : this.noStyle;
}
```

It is important, that `noStyle` and `gT100Style` are defined outside `getStyle()` otherwise change detection would cause troubles because every call would return a new style object instance.

This should work as well:

```
<span *ngIf="result.object.reference > 100" class="tooltip-data" 
    [ngStyle]="id > 100 ? {left: '12px'} : {}">
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/LHgD19ipVcXwUGMsd0fO?p=preview)

Comment: And what do you mean with this: `getStyle(id) {
  return id > 100 ? this.gT100Style : this.noStyle;
}
 `
it does the same as above or how can I set which needs that styling and which not?

Comment: The difference is that the first 2 examples set `left: 0px` for `id<=100` while the last example should not set any style at all if `id<=100` because it returns an empty object `{}`.  Actually this would work inline as well. I'll add another example.